# How to get Azure Function name from within a function using C# script (csx)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

My goal is to provide a code snippet to customers. One file will contain customer's business logic, another file will provide its handling. For the latter I need to have a name of a function [would like to avoid asking customers to enter this information manually].

I searched around but could not figure out. Essentially I need this:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `ExecutionContext` class has a property `FunctionName` ([docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/v2.x/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Core/ExecutionContext.cs))

You can inject the class like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("HttpTriggered")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
     HttpRequest req, 
     ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
     var name = executionContext.FunctionName;
     ...
}
```

The output will be

> HttpTriggered